# How do I update data in magical records

Tags: iphone, core-data, swift2, magicalrecord

I am using core data in my swift project and I am using magical record for core data I want to edit already saved data.

I am fetching editing task like this:

```
 array = Tasks.MR_findByAttribute("task_name", withValue: entryLabel.text)
```

I am getting data which I want to edit. I am not understanding how to edit this and save in the place of old record. Can anyone please tell me the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In MagicalRecord, you modify data the same way you would with plain Core Data:

- fetch
- change attributes / relationships
- save

The most commonly used API in MagicalRecord for this is the class method `saveWithBlock`. In the block you fetch your entities and modify them.